# how can i add VB6 Adodc.recordset.find

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to search and display my database on textbox using VB6, but im not quite sure where the problem is,how would i display my data base in textboxes after i search for it?

I've aldready tried different set of codes but none seems to work. i've also tried the inputbox.

```
Dim search As String

search = Text5.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Find "Studno = " & search

If Adodc1.Recordset.EOF Then
MsgBox "NO record"
Else
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Studno") = Text1.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Studname") = Text2.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Age") = Text3.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Address") = Text4.Text
End If
```

i would like to display all the fields in the textboxes after i searched for the studno.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add the content of the textboxes to the recordset fields rather than the other way round. Try:

```
Text1.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Studno")
Text2.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Studname")
Text3.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Age")
Text4.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Address")
```

Comment: hi, my main problem is how would adodc search it then display them in the else statement, i think my code lacks something

Dim search As String

search = Text5.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Find "Studno = " & search

Comment: Ah ok. So your code isn't actually finding anything. Are you searching for a string or a number? If it's a string you'll need to put quotes round the string you're looking for:

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Updated answer. Try:

```
Adodc1.Recordset.Find "Studno = '" & search & "'"
```

and put a breakpoint on the first line after the `Else` statement to make sure it's getting that far. (Note there is a single quote both before and after the search string.)
 You'll still need the changes I posted originally to actually see the results.

Comment: hi again, so my code runs, but it doesn't display the content on the textboxes, also it only works on the else statement, the code goes like this,


Dim search As String
search = Text5.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Find "Studno = '" & search & "'"
If Adodc1.Recordset.EOF = True Then
MsgBox "NO record"
Else
MsgBox "Record Found"
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Studno") = Text1.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Studname") = Text2.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Age") = Text3.Text
Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Address") = Text4.Text
End If

Comment: You haven't changed the rest of the code as in my first answer! You're still trying to insert the contents of the text boxes into the recordset rather than the other way round. Read the statements from left to right and think about what you're trying to do.